# jQuery Regex expression to test email or number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email

I'm using jQuery's regex expression to validate emails input by users. The emails could be either regular emails or a string of purely numbers. Currently it works fine except it cannot detect wrong suffix such as 'cpm' and 'con', which are all wrong spellings of 'com'.

Code:

```
var regex_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
if (regex_email.test(email) || email.match(/^\d+$/)){
    // .....
}
```

Any advice on a more robust validator to weed out those wrong suffix mentioned above?

Best,

Comment: Given the vast number of domain extensions, validating it is highly impractical - the Regex would be ***gigantic***. All you can really do is make sure the format matched the spec and send a test email to the address and mark it as confirmed by clicking a link in that email.

Comment: Cool. I agree. BTW what about just taking out those most common wrong spellings such as 'cpm', 'con'?

Comment: You never know what legitimate url's could pop up in the future though